# Django template not rendering at all

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have all my django views and templates working, however, when i tried to make this new, simple one it simply wouldn't render.

views.py:

```
def ListRefView2(request):
    return render(request, "reference/test.html", context)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ListRefView,
    ListRefView2, 
    CreateRefView, 
    DetailRefView, 
    UpdateRefView, 
    DeleteRefView,
)
 
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', ListRefView),
    path('test2/', ListRefView2),
    path('<str:slug>/delete/', DeleteRefView),
    path('<str:slug>/edit/', UpdateRefView),
    path('<str:slug>/', DetailRefView),
    path('test2/', ListRefView2)
]
```

test.html

```
<h1>Hello </h1>
```

I am trying to get "Hello" to show up via the "ListRefView2" view

Comment: Exactly *what* error do you get?

Comment: Its a 404 error and at the bottom it says "No referencePost matches the given query."

Comment: Where is `context` defined? It's not defined in your view

Comment: @wick123: it looks like you are querying the *wrong* view.

Comment: @IainShelvington, i removed the context and it still wouldnt work.

Comment: @wick123 `'<str:slug>/'` matches the pattern `'test2/'` so `DetailRefView` is used for that... (A referencePost can have the slug `test2`)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How so?

Comment: @wick123: the error says it aims to fetch a `Post` object from the database, but your view does not make any query to the `Post` model.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat the first `test2/` path will be matched against first, since it's before the `'<str:slug>/'` path. Duplicate paths are confusing things

Comment: @IainShelvington didn't even notice that duplicate pattern, still considering the error most likely there is some other matching pattern. Perhaps this should be put in the tag wiki or something considering it is such a common problem.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I agree, there is fairly large issue with people not understanding the URL resolver

Comment: @wick123 show the _complete_ error traceback. Also show your other url patterns for instance your project level url patterns etc.

Comment: The duplicate pattern was removed, i was just re-ordering the urls and forgot to remove the duplicate pattern, so no thats not the issue.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The 404 error specifies it is a 'GET' method. The 'referencePost' is the name of one of my models. im not sure why thats even showing up there tbh

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry, i just understood what you said, Thank you very much for the help, it works now. it basically matches another url.